# How to display a certain set of data File Handling C

Tags: c, file-handling

so I am thinking if there's a way that I could display one set of data inputted. So my sample program operates like this: 
The user inputs a name, gender, and an age. The user can input multiple data. But I want to add a function where the user will type in a name, and then displays the name, and its corresponding gender, and age. But the thing is, I have no idea to do that. I heard of a function `fseek()` but I think it just edits the value; for example, age or gender.

Here is my sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct clientName {
    char name[30];
    char gender[10];
};

struct clientAge {
    int age;
};

void main() {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("data.txt", "ab");

    struct clientName NAME;
    struct clientAge AGE;

    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("Error");
        getch();
    } else {
        system("cls");
        printf("Enter Name: ");
        gets(NAME.name);

        printf("Enter Gender: ");
        gets(NAME.gender);

        printf("Enter Age: ");
        scanf("%d", &AGE.age);

        fwrite((char *)&NAME, sizeof(struct clientName), 1, fp);
        fwrite((char *)&AGE, sizeof(struct clientAge), 1, fp);
        printf("\n\nData Added");
        fclose(fp);

     }

     system("cls");
     fp = fopen("data.txt", "rb");

     while((fread((char *)&NAME, sizeof(struct clientName), 1, fp)) == 1 & (fread((char *)&AGE, sizeof(struct clientAge), 1, fp)) == 1) {

         printf("%s", NAME.name);
         printf("       %s", NAME.gender);
         printf("      %d y/o", AGE.age);
         printf("\n");  
    }

    fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: The first thing to learn now would be to indent the code properly. That is unreadable. The second would be to remove all these `(char *)` casts, they can make your code only more wrong.

Comment: Also your problem is that you're not closing the file after the *writes*.  `fclose(fp)` before the latter read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems i see with your code. I'll first try to correct it and then provide a full example of how I would do what you want done.

```
struct clientName {
    char name[30];
    char gender[10];
};

struct clientAge {
    int age;
};
```

Why are you using 2 structs for 1 dataset?

Use

```
struct data
{
    char name[30];
    char gender[10];
    int age;
};
```

instead.

```
   fwrite((char *)&NAME, sizeof(struct clientName), 1, fp);
```

can be written as: `fwrite(&client, sizeof(client), 1, fp);`

```
     while((fread((char *)&NAME, sizeof(struct clientName), 1, fp)) == 1 
& (fread((char *)&AGE, sizeof(struct clientAge), 1, fp)) == 1)
```

can be written as: `while (fread(&client, sizeof(client), 1, fp))`

after which you only have to compare the client.name variable with your user input name like so:

```
    if (strcmp(client.name, input) == 0)
```

Please note that I only opted to use one struct on purpose, as I do not see why it would be beneficial to use 2 structs in your use case.
If you, however do need to use 2 structs you can simply add an 'ID' integer variable to both of them and find all data points to any given name that way.

Full code example:

```
struct data
{
    char name[30];
    char gender[10];
    int age;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct data client;
    FILE* fp;
    char ch = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter Name: ");
        scanf("%s", client.name);

        printf("Enter Gender: ");
        scanf("%s", client.gender);

        printf("Enter Age: ");
        scanf("%d", &client.age);

        fp = fopen("Data.dat", "ab");
        fwrite(&client, sizeof(client), 1, fp);
        fclose(fp);
        printf("continue? \n");
        scanf(" %c", &ch);
    } while (ch != 'n'); // continuously appends file till letter n is read;

    char input[30]; // user input
    printf("name?\n"); // please note that you could pretty much use every other data point here.
    scanf("%s", input);

    struct data Read; // used different for showcasing purposes only
    fp = fopen("Data.dat", "rb");
    while (fread(&client, sizeof(client), 1, fp))
    {
        if (strcmp(client.name, input) == 0) // compare variable with user input
        {
            printf("%s", client.name);
            printf("       %s", client.gender);
            printf("      %d y/o", client.age);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you man, this worked! But may I ask a question? what is this `Read` on `struct data Read`?

Comment: Its a different data "object" in order to showcase that the data gets read from file(figured that might not be all that obvious otherwise). In other words it can be omitted and probably should be.